# Outputting values of array

Tags: php, foreach

I have the following array:

```
array(20) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["href"]=>
    string(112) "http://blogs.msdn.com/b/..."
    ["title"]=>
    string(50) "How to improve performance ..."
    ["dateCreated"]=>
    string(11) "03 apr 2012"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["href"]=>
    string(104) "http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ ..."
    ["title"]=>
    string(98) "Activating Windows 8 c..."
    ["dateCreated"]=>
    string(11) "24 mar 2012"
  }
```

All I want to be able to do is output the values of the array, something like:

```
foreach($array as $item) {
    $item->href?
}
```

This should be simple but Im struggling this evening.

Answer (score 3):

Erm... same way as you'd output anything else. With [`echo`](http://php.net/echo).

```
foreach($array as $item) {
    echo $item['href'];
}
```

Revise basics on [arrays](http://php.net/array) too.

Answer (score 1):

With type-casting you can change the array into an object, like so:

```
<?php
foreach ( $array as $item ) 
{
    $item = (object)$item;
    echo $item->href;
}
?>
```

If you retrieved the data from a database, you could also use `mysqli_fetch_object()` which will return the data as an object and not an array.

PHP.net on [mysqli_fetch_object()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php)

Or, if using it like an object doesn't interest you, simply use `echo $item['href'];` instead of `echo $item->href;`